# Optimizing website menu

Tags: templating, entries

I have created a global menu for my website and there I have a label and an entry section selection that I use for directing when clicking.

However, I just need the URL of that section and loading the whole section data is way too much overhead that its not needed.

I have 4-5 menu items so I am loading 4-5 sections for no reason.  Imagine the overhead.

Can I somehow use the section selector in CMS but get only the section URL without loading all the section data?

Answer (score 1):

Are you experiencing performance issues? If not, is this overhead really an issue?

If it is, how about caching the global menu for a really long time? https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/cache

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would create much overhead, but everyone's setup is different.

Try this test. Enable [Dev Mode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), and create a test template with the following code:

```
{% for section in craft.sections.getAllSections() %}
    {{ section.name }}: {{ section.getUrlFormat() }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Then load this up in a browser and look at the [JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/). You should see entries starting with "Profiling Summary Report" that will list execution time, memory and total queries.

Running this code locally on the [Happy Lager demo site](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager), I get these results:

```
Profiling Summary Report
  Time:   0.30656s
  Memory: 10,799Kb
  Total Queries: 19
```